# Is there a way to customize a duplicated class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am still relatively new to coding and only still learning dart. I have made multiple of the same button using classes, how do i customize each button individually, please can you help. Here is the code:
Button Code:

```
class JeffButton extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 85,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                'Label',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        label: Text(
          '', //'Label',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Other Code:

```
class home_buttons {
  List<Widget> jeffButtons = [
  JeffButton(),
  JeffButton(),
  JeffButton(),
  JeffButton(),
  JeffButton(),
  JeffButton(),
];
}
```

Comment: You can pass properties through the class's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have properties on your class - That way, when you create instances of your button, you can pass different values as arguments to the constructor, and those different values can be used to customize each instance of the button.

So, for example, if you want to customize the title label, give your class a `title` property:

```
class JeffButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  JeffButton({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => {},
        label: Text(
          title, // Use the title property to set the label text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can set different titles for each button:

```
final continueButton = JeffButton(title: 'Continue');
final cancelButton = JeffButton(title: 'Cancel');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructors, here is an example for padding.

```
class JeffButton extends StatelessWidget {

   EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;      

   JeffButton({this.padding = EdgeInsets.all(8)});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  Padding(
      padding: padding,
    );
    
   }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
JeffButton(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10));
```